# is it possible es aggreation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a question about aggregation.

I want to do aggregation for a field declared as an object array.
It is not aggregation for each element, but aggregation for the whole value.

I have following documents:

```
PUT value-list-index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "server": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "users": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


PUT value-list-index/_doc/1
{
    "server": "server1",
    "users": ["user1"]
}

PUT value-list-index/_doc/2
{
    "server": "server2",
    "users": ["user1","user2"]
}

PUT value-list-index/_doc/3
{
    "server": "server3",
    "users": ["user2", "user3"]
}

PUT value-list-index/_doc/4
{
    "server": "server4",
    "users": ["user1","user2", "user3","user4"]
}

PUT value-list-index/_doc/5
{
    "server": "server5",
    "users": ["user2", "user3","user4"]
}

PUT value-list-index/_doc/6
{
    "server": "server6",
    "users": ["user3","user4"]
}

PUT value-list-index/_doc/7
{
    "server": "server7",
    "users": ["user1","user2", "user3","user4"]
}

PUT value-list-index/_doc/8
{
    "server": "server8",
    "users": ["user1","user2", "user3","user4"]
}

PUT value-list-index/_doc/9
{
    "server": "server9",
    "users": ["user1","user2", "user3","user4"]
}
```

```
get value-list-index/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "words": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "users"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "users"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i want following

```
"aggregations" : {
    "words" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          **"key" : "user1",
          "doc_count" : 1,**
          "total" : {
            "value" : xx
          }
        },
        {
          **"key" : "user1","user2",
          "doc_count" : 1,**
          "total" : {
            "value" : xx
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "user1","user2","user3","user4",
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "total" : {
            "value" : xx
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

but return each element grouping result like this

```
"aggregations" : {
    "words" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "user2",
          "doc_count" : 7,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 23
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "user3",
          "doc_count" : 7,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 23
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "user1",
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 19
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "user4",
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 21
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Is the aggregation I want possible?

Comment: do you want to know the number repetitions array by document?

Comment: yes,I want to get the result like below
[key : user1  count : 10],[key: user1, user2 count: x],[key: user1, user2,user3 count: x]....
not each element, [user1, count:x][user2, count:xx][user3, count:xxx][user4, count:xxxxx]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this aggs can help you: [Frequent items aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-frequent-items-aggregation.html)

But be careful with the performance.

Look this results:

```
"aggregations": {
    "words": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": {
            "users": [
              "user2"
            ]
          },
          "doc_count": 7,
          "support": 0.7777777777777778
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "users": [
              "user2",
              "user3"
            ]
          },
          "doc_count": 6,
          "support": 0.6666666666666666
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "users": [
              "user3",
              "user4"
            ]
          },
          "doc_count": 6,
          "support": 0.6666666666666666
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "users": [
              "user1"
            ]
          },
          "doc_count": 6,
          "support": 0.6666666666666666
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "users": [
              "user2",
              "user3",
              "user4"
            ]
          },
          "doc_count": 5,
          "support": 0.5555555555555556
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "users": [
              "user2",
              "user1"
            ]
          },
          "doc_count": 5,
          "support": 0.5555555555555556
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "users": [
              "user2",
              "user3",
              "user4",
              "user1"
            ]
          },
          "doc_count": 4,
          "support": 0.4444444444444444
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```